# Solving Polytropic equation for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a Polytropic equation which ends up in the following form:

$$
ax^2=(1-x)^{1/2}\,\,\,\Rightarrow{ax^{4}=1-x}
$$
How would I solve this for $x$? An approximation would be sufficient...

Comment: It is a quartic that you can solve (with fun). How big is $a$ ? Or how large is supposed to be $x$ compared to $1$ ?

Comment: a is exactly 0.01805.

Comment: With a numerical solver, $x\approx0.9831370534161$ or $x\approx-4.0998745921613$. For small $a$, a good starting value for Newton's iterations should be $1-a$.

Comment: Using Newton's Method would give a good approximation, but it requires some calculations.

Comment: What would be the method for obtaining these numerical values? A very powerful computer?

Comment: If you can wait 1 millisecond to get the answer, an old Apple II computer running interpreted Basic should do. (I mean: this is a very light computation.)

Comment: Haha, of course. I meant generally will it take a computer or can this be done with old fashioned quill and ink?

Comment: A skilled by-hand calculator would probably take half an hour to get four or five correct decimals (there are divisions involved). Like two minutes with a simple (4 operations) calculator. There are many other options like pre-tabulating or computing a Taylor's development or approximation polynomial... Why are you asking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small $a$, there is a solution close to $1$, let $1-\epsilon$. Then

$$a(1-\epsilon)^4=\epsilon.$$

If you develop the power to the first order by the Binomial theorem,

$$a(1-4\epsilon)\approx\epsilon,$$

or

$$x=1-\epsilon\approx 1-\frac a{4a+1}=0.9831654542063.$$
If you develop to one more term,

$$a(1-4\epsilon+6\epsilon^2)\approx\epsilon,$$

or

$$6a\epsilon^2-(4a+1)\epsilon+a=0.$$

Solving the quadratic equation yields

$$x=1-\epsilon\approx 0.9831367307829.$$

The plot below shows the curve of $x$ as a function of $a$ (in blue), the first order approximation (in green) and the second order (in red).

[image]